# Pervasive, open DAT file with JAVA SDK - JCL SDK for Windows

Tags: java, database, pervasive

Is there any way with JAVA to open Pervasive **DAT file directly with SDK** – see the attachment - https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1lhSNdHpbprc1FrSGlMOWNVWnM - with that SDK?

JCL SDK for Windows from http://www.pervasivedb.com/support/Pages/PSQLSDK-Archives.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access a DAT file using the JCL interface but you will need a few things.  The JCL driver itself cannot access the file.  The driver needs an engine to open the file. 
You will also need to know the **exact** record layout of the file.
Once you have those things, you can use the JCL driver to access Btrieve files.  Take a look at http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=jcl/java_api.2.4.html#23324.  It describes how to access a "loosely coupled" database, one that does not have DDFs.  I have a sample somewhere.  I'll look for it and post it if I can find it.